# Smarty regex replace Ordernumber

Tags: regex, replace, smarty

I have an Ordernumber that looks like this: `1001-00001.2` but I want it without the extra `.2`

I tried to use the following in my code:

```
{$sArticle.ordernumber|regex_replace:"/'.'/\d":" "}
```

it didn't work because I don't know how I can use the dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dot matches any single character. Try escaping it:

```
{$sArticle.ordernumber|regex_replace:"/\.\d+$/":""}
```

There's actually a few changes, here.

- Everything was moved to be within the `/.../` that mark a regex
- The dot was escaped with `\`.
- A quantifier (`+`) was added to `\d` so it matches one *or more* digits.
- An anchor (`$`) is used to make sure it doesn't match anywhere but the end of the string.
- The replacement is now an empty string